# What's up with the `- <string>` in Google search result

Tags: google, google-search, title

I recently did a google search of [an article](http://0a.io/0a-explains-calculus) I wrote and this is what I see:

[image]

If I am not wrong the string behind `-` should be the title of the original website, which is never "v1.0".

[image]

Actually, nowhere in my website did I indicate that "v1.0" is the title or anything significant.

```
<title>0a explains: Calculus (with pics and gifs)</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="keywords" content="0a, Calculus, Differentiation, Integration">
<meta name="author" content="Archy Wilhes">
<meta name="description" content="Calculus explained with pics and gifs. Written in possibly (hopefully) the most comprehensible way for anyone who is new to limit, differentiation and integration. ">
```

It just happened to be the first string of characters in the website besides my logo which is a png.

```
<div class="logo inline">
<img src="assets/img/0a.png">
<div class="version">v1.0</div>
</div>
```

So is there a way to change it to something else? All I can think of is doing a bit of "hack" like putting a display-none string in front of v.10.

Comment: Well, Google does do things like this. Titles (and descriptions) in the SERPs are manipulated to supposedly return something more relevant for the user. It's the first bit of text in a `<header>` and it looks like version information, so it's not completely illogical. I don't think that putting a `display:none` string _in front_ would necessarily help, I would think you would need to manipulate the text itself?

Answer (score 1):

Thats kinda strange. Im assuming its because v1.0 is the first words on the page and because you put the string inside of a logo div. Normally Google would pull the fallback/alt/title site name from that logo div innards. Since you have no alt+title on the img, its using the next div assuming its in text logo fallback. Google uses class/id names in a manner similar to how it uses Schema.org. Maybe just changing the class from "version" to something else would help. If it doesn't, you could try wrapping the "logo" div in another more general one called something like "mid" and splitting "version" out of "logo" div.

You can also try making titles longer to boot the dynamic string(s) off the SERP widget. Here is how long that title would be at 60 chars `0a explains: Calculus (with pics and gifs) - 123456789012345`